# XNA copy element, not assign refernce to it

Tags: c#, xna, copy

I know when an assignment statement is made a new object is not made, a reference to the object is made instead. For instance I want to do the following:

```
 word.start = newWordPos.First.Value;
 word.end = newWordPos.Last.Value;
```

But every time the values of `newWordPos.First.Value` or `newWordPos.Last.Value` is updated, then `word.start` and `word.end` are updated as well. Is there any way I can get them to be assigned the actual value so that this does not occur?

Comment: you need to give us more information/code. It's not clear from those two lines of code what types you're working with, so it's hard to answer your question atm.. It looks like you might be working with Nullable value types here? Again, we can only guess at this point..

Answer (score 0):

Since your type is a class, you need to *clone* the object, not just assign a reference.

The type itself needs to provide some mechanism of creating a deep copy.  The framework provides an interface ([`IClonable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx)) which is for allowing a single `Clone` method - though it's not clear what form of cloning is being done (ie: full deep clone, etc).

Comment: I have been look around online and found a bunch of sites talking about that. The data I want to copy is of type Vector2 provided by the XNA Framework. I'm not sure how to go about implementing the method for the Vector2 class.

Comment: @McAvoy: Since it's an XNA Vector2, it's a struct.  It already is doing a full copy - so you don't need to clone it.

Comment: then why do the values change every time the vectors in the list are changed